# Magic as a programming language

Tags: magic

Implementing a magic system as a programming language is very difficult. Does anyone have any advice, prior work, guiding ideas, or tips for doing this?

The idea is that I want to be able to make a magic system where spells can be created like software developers create programs in a programming language. Imagine you sit down, type up some code in functions that describe various sub-functionality of the spell within the magic system, then those pieces are composed together to create a working spell.

I’m trying to create a system that accurately fills this goal of “spells as code”, to a sufficient extent that it could be implemented and ran on a personal computer in 2020.

Work so far:

I’m aware of some games like [Magika](https://store.steampowered.com/app/42910/Magicka/) that are sort of close, and some stories that use this idea, but stop shy of providing the full details.

I’m aware of the field of [Artificial Chemistry,](http://web.cs.mun.ca/%7Ebanzhaf/papers/alchemistry_review_MIT.pdf) which seems promising as providing a chemical baseline on some level.

[CodeSpells](https://store.steampowered.com/app/324190/CodeSpells/) is pretty great, and a decent example of the kind of thing I’m looking for.

I have plenty of other brainstorming ideas, some of which are in the edits, but if anyone has tried to do this before and has advice or thoughts I’d really appreciate it.

Edit: Some of the comments below are referring to how this question used to be about “formalizing fantasy magic”, a less precise statement. Magic as code is what I wanted to ask about, and it’s a better way of phrasing the idea that communicates the important aspects.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111669/discussion-on-question-by-phylliida-magic-as-a-programming-language).

Answer (score 8):

### Elements of a Programmable Magic System

In order to have a programmable magic system like you are asking for, there are a few principles of programming you will want to consider in it's design.

**A [Library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_(computing)) of Primitives:**

Without predefined objects defining what a spell is and does, you do not have a spell crafting programing language, you just have a programing language.  Your primitives are the basic building blocks of your system that tells the end user what abilities are at his disposal.  So, all the code responsible for a spell would fall inside of this system of object classes that can be bound together to make a spell. Your Primitives are used to set both the ability and limits on spells; so, if I want to include teleport spell, the primitive called `teleport` would include inside it not just the code for moving a character between points, but formulas for determining mana cost, cool down timers, range limits, etc.

**An Isolated [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID) [API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface) Architecture:**

While this is generally a good idea in programming, it is 100% essential for any system that gives an end user this much access to parts of how your game runs.  In short, you will want your primitives and game engine completely isolated from your magic programming interface by an API such that making a spell means using just the primitives and interfaces that the game's developer has given you.  If a `fire-attack` has certain properties and procedures for establishing cost and potency, you don't want users to have access to change these properties and procedures.  You just want them to call and extend on them.  Red-stone programming is a good example of this.  It does not let you change how minecraft works, it just lets you take certain things that you can already do in the game and build procedures to do it in useful patterns.

**[Turing Completeness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness):**

The difference between a spell crafting system like you see in Elder Scrolls and a spell programming system would be the ability to string things together in logical and repeatable operations.  Including things like logical operators (and, if, or, etc.), recursive operators (while, for, goto, etc.), and the ability to define your own variables with your spells will allow players nearly infinite access to manipulate the logic behind spell casting.

**Make the system accessible to a wide audience**:

Another feature I would suggest is to make spells able to be encrypted, shared, and sold.  Most players will not want to program thier own spells in this much detail, but those that do will love it, and be able to make very advanced spells this way.  By letting people hide the code of thier own spells to other players, it would encourage them to sell high-end spells on the community market.

Using these principles, your "spell-book" might look something like this on the back-end, but hand coding could be substituted with a [Visual Programming Interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_programming_language) to reduce the leaning curve.

```
spell pummel($damage-low = 15, $damage-high = 30, $stunChance = 100, $stunDuration = 1){ 
  // Metadata like name, description, and permission can be added to your custom spells to help with non-casty in-game stuff.
  this.name = 'Throw Pummel';
  this.description = 'A simple attack spell for ending your foe rightly!';
  this.permission = 'public';
  cast ranged-attack({ // ranged-attack is a primitive for casting a spell which has certain properties you can define.
    element = 'kinetic',
    damage-low = $damage-low,
    damage-high = $damage-high,
    range = 50,
    accuracy = 80,
    stunChance = $stunChance,
    stunDuration = $stunDuration,
    special-effect = "bolt",
    special-effect-tint = "rgba(0,255,255,.75)"
  }
}

spell chainPummel() (){
  this.name = 'Chain Pummel';
  this.description = 'Pummel up to 10 enemies in a row!';
  this.permission = 'private';
  for(i=0;i<10;i++){
    if (target.alive == true) { // target is an API behavior allowing an interaction with the game-engine.
      cast pummel(5, 10, 100, .1); // pummel has now been defined as an instance of ranged-attack which can now be called like a primitive. Also, by passing variables with it you can customize the spell on the fly.  In this case, by casting a weaker/cheaper version of the spell.
      delay (0.1); 
    } else {
      setNewTarget('hostile'); // setNewTarget is an API behavior allowing an interaction with the game-engine.
      if (target.alive == true) {
        cast pummel(5, 10, 100, .1);
        delay (0.1); 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can see that there is a lot of control here to make unique and quite intelligent spells, but no where does this say what the spells will cost to cast or let you directly manipulate the environment. So, your game interface will need to calculate and output those details for you; so, if I were to sell you these spells, your spell book might look like this:

> **Throw Pummel** [edit]
>
> Lvl.3 Spell (costs 55 mana)
>
> A simple attack spell for ending your foe rightly!
>
> Author: Nosajimiki

> **Chain Pummel**
>
> Lvl.6 Spell (costs 21-210 mana)
>
> *Prereqs: Throw Pummel*
>
> Pummel up to 10 enemies in a row!
>
> Author: Nosajimiki

*Original answer may prove helpful for context, but does not answer the question as it has been revised.*

### Yes, it's been tried

Yes, first place I remember seeing something like that is in the magic crafting system in Elder Scrolls:Oblivion.  Basically you could combine any combination of spell properties to create custom spells and the difficulty to cast the spell was based on what properties you gave it.  So, you could take a fire spell and decide if you wanted it to be touch or ranged, add a blast radius if you want it to be AOE, and you could then add a DoT property if you wanted it to burn instead of do all the damage at once, etc. and all the different properties of a spell either made it more or less expensive to cast so you could balance it however you wanted it.

While the game had a bunch of ready-made spells for noobs to start with, once you got in good with the mages guild, these procedurally built spells literally allowed for millions of combinations of spells based on just a small handful of properties that had to be discreetly designed by the developers.

It had an alchemy system for brewing potions procedurally based on what ingredients you used too.

### How to make it more of a "science"

The thing about systems like the one used by Elder Scrolls was that it was designed to be as balanced and intuitive as possible; so, in the end it does not matter how you customized a spell, you'd never really hit much above your weight class just by using a cleaver combination of elements.

For this you need a system that is asymmetric, exploitable, and full of undocumented features.

Now this sounds like a terrible premise for game design, if a game has enough strange mechanics that are not explained in game, then researching and experimenting to see what they are becomes a meaningful part  of the game unto itself.

**How you could apply this to a magic system:**

In the spell crafting section of the game you could choose what element you want an attack to be (fire, wind, water, and earth).  On paper they all do the same damage and cost the same mana; so, being a noob, you just pick one at random.  The game does not tell you this, but earth spells do a little extra armor penetration against heavy armor, fire spells have a higher crit rate,  water spells can interrupt another player's spells, and wind pushed the opponent back a little.  So, only through playing the game and making observations do you learn there are cases where one is better than the other.  You may also notice that as you add levels to each element that they scale differently.  Both 1 level of fire damage and one level of wind damage do 10 points of damage, but a level 5 fire does 50 damage, and wind only does 30, unless you can use the push effect to slam the opponent against a wall in which case you do 60.

Then you can make things even more confusing with environmental variables like.  Fire spells can be blinding bright when cast at night, water spells do less damage in a desert, wind spells are much less useful in open areas with nothing to push people into, and earth spells might do different damage based on what kind of ground you are standing on.

So what this means for game play is that a wise wizard may know that he is going up against a mage who prefers Earth spells; so, he puts on some gambeson armor so he can move faster and absorb the impacts.  He then lures the other wizard out onto a sandy beach so that his bolder spell suddenly starts throwing balls of mostly harmless sand.  He then drinks a potion of x-ray vision and casts a wind AOE spell to kick up cloud of sand to blind his opponent.  So, while the wiser wizard may be a lower level, he could still utterly destroy his opponent if he's thoroughly researched the side effects of spells and abilities.

Another layer of complexity could be that the ratios of levels you put into a spell has certain optimal levels; so, a spell that does Fire damage may do the most damage per level of fire damage if 50% of the spells levels are devoted to damage, but more or less and you get a diminishing return

> To phrase this a different way: I want a set of physics rules that
> allows players to create spells in game as various sorts of
> “technology”. Similar to how players build red stone flying machines
> from red stone and pistons in Minecraft,

Add a system for making spell combo macros.  Where your spell tray can trigger conditional logic that activates spells and abilities.  So, let's say your system does not allow flight, but it does allow mid-air jumping, you might create a macro that turns on and off looping  mid-air jumping.  Many gamers build macros to "cheat" anyway, you'd just make it a part of the game to begin with.

Comment: Very nice, I was not aware of that system, but it is much closer to what I was looking for. In general, the direction you are brainstorming is along the lines of what I was looking for, thanks :) Just one point: I would argue that hiding the details isn’t necessary, as long as some system like the one you are describing exists, with some benefits and weaknesses to various types (and making the weaknesses and strengths partially environmental is a interesting idea)Besides, eventually players would figure it out and post on wikis and it would be similar to having the rules publicly shared anyway

Comment: Yes but with unpublished values, wikis and player guides will be inconstant, incomplete, and contain false observations (just like real science).  If PvP is a major aspect of your game, then you will tend to see a lot of low-to-mid quality wikis that discuss what you want to know to get started whereas major factions will tend to uncover stuff that is not common knowledge and exercise OpSec to protect that info. StarMade was a mine-craft like game that saw a lot of that, and the top players did stuff for months or even years before you'd see in any wiki.

Comment: I agree, it's not strictly necessary, but it will expand the player knowledge gap meaning your system does not strictly speaking need a leveling system so much.  This means you can get rid of grinding and let actually player experience and knowledge take center stage... or you could make rapid leveling with perma-death finally make since in an MMO if player's experience could out weigh character abilities.

Comment: @Phylliida Note, this same type of magic system (which itself is based off of how D&D spells are actually "made" or at least balanced) is used in a lot of books which include some sort of enchanting or scripting or enhancement magic (where magic is made by combining engravings of some sort). [Sufficiently Advanced Mage](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/34403860-sufficiently-advanced-magic) has one of my favorite systems but there are many other examples like this (even the semi-magic system of King Killer series).

Comment: @Phylliida your updated question makes what you are asking much more clear, see my revised answer.

Answer (score 2):

**Calculus**

Sometimes the answer can be easy and cheeky. Any spell needs to be calculated and understood. A fireball? You need to calculate the volume, heat, material it burns on, how it travels and *understand* it all. This has many advantages.

- Your world literally works on Calculus, making a everything computable.
- Focus is simply how well you can focus on the calculations. More calculations means more tiredness and thus less focus. It returns after a bit, unless you did too many and need some more rest.
- It limits itself. You can calculate a nuclear explosion, but you cannot *understand* it. A candle or campfire is understandable. A nuclear explosion is simply so big we have nothing to relate it to.
- Some facets are more understanding based. Taking over someone's mind requires understanding them and can't really be calculated.
- Differences in understanding and calculating of different subjects shows the differences in magic ability.
- Progression is done by experience. If you're more experienced in calculating and understanding things, it can get easier.

You might think lots is too difficult to calculate. But with many things it's calculating from an ideal perspective. Like many physics using a vacuum and spherical objects etc. Using it on real world objects means you need to know more about the environment.

Understanding would also prevent computers from simply calculating things whenever they see fit. If something is inscribed with a formula, it'll only be magic if it is understood. This way blocks like the redstone machines can be created, each with their own function.

The world runs on an unseen calculating power. If things are out of view, it requires less calculating power. Thus it can run faster if no one is watching the magic happen.

Comment: This is the method used in Ra, and in principle I quite like it. It’s also very nice for world building magic. However, in practice, it doesn’t really satisfy my requirement 1, as there is no way (yet) for a computer to know if someone understands something. However I might be misunderstanding and you mean “the user must specify a program that does these calculations” as a form of understanding. In this case, the system is implementable, though we still haven’t addressed the underlying problem of what the magic physics actually are, so we’ve just solved a sub problem of the general question.

Comment: You allude to the physics question in the statement that all properties must be fully calculated. I quite like that idea in principle, and think taking it further may have some promise.

Comment: Reminds me somewhat of "Irregular at magic high school" It is on netflix.

Comment: @ITAlex You think you have an original idea based on what is requested, and it's already somewhere.

Comment: @Trioxidane the originality is in the details! I for one enjoy new and interesting implementations of already existing genres and tropes.